# Error occuring when I try to run decorator with @ - Python

Tags: python, decorator

I am having a problem with the following programm.
When I try to run decorator the easier way, using @ like this

```
def decorator1(fun):
    def wrapper():
        text = '------'
        return text + '\n' + fun + '\n' + text

    return wrapper()


def decorator2(fun):
    def wrapper():
        return fun.upper()

    return wrapper()

@decorator1
@decorator2
def function():
    return "Hey ya!"


print(function())
```

Following problems occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    def function():
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 13, in decorator2
    return wrapper()
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return fun.upper()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

or when I switch the order of decorators then it goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    def function():
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 6, in decorator1
    return wrapper()
  File "C:\Python_projects\main.py", line 4, in wrapper
    return text + '\n' + fun + '\n' + text
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "function") to str
```

When I run the code in this way, then it works just fine:

```
def decorator1(fun):
    def wrapper():
        text = '------'
        return text + '\n' + fun + '\n' + text

    return wrapper()

def decorator2(fun):
    def wrapper():
        return fun.upper()

    return wrapper()

def function():
    return "Hey ya!"
 

print(decorator(decorator2(function())))
```

But it seems like using @ with decorators is much more popular. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If `fun` is a function, what is `fun.upper()` supposed to be? Did you want `fun().upper()`?

Comment: Also, you are supposed to return the wrapper from the decorator, not invoke it

Comment: Right, but when I type `fun().upper()` then the working code with  `print(decorator(decorator2(function())))` is not working anymore becasue of `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decorator is a function which is run on another *function*, as in a *function object*, not the result of another function.
So:

```py
@decorator
def func():
    ...
```

Is equivalent to:

```py
def func():
    ...
func = decorator(func)
```

Notice that the function `func` has never actually been called.

Therefore, within the wrapper function within the decorator, you actually need to call the function yourself. Use, for example, `fun().upper()`, not `fun.upper()`.

Also, the wrapper function should never be called within the decorator; the function itself should be returned, so `return wrapper` not `return wrapper()`.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
def decorator1(fun):
    def wrapper():
        text = '------'
        return text + '\n' + fun() + '\n' + text

    return wrapper


def decorator2(fun):
    def wrapper():
        return fun().upper()

    return wrapper

@decorator1
@decorator2
def function():
    return "Hey ya!"


print(function())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a decorator is a function that accepts a function and returns a function. Thus, do not call the `wrapper`, but return it. Moreover, the `fun` method should be called.

```py
def decorator1(fun):
    def wrapper():
        text = "------"
        return text + "\n" + fun() + "\n" + text

    return wrapper


def decorator2(fun):
    def wrapper():
        return fun().upper()

    return wrapper


@decorator1
@decorator2
def function():
    return "Hey ya!"


print(function())
```

Note that those decorators will work only with functions (or callables in general) that return `str` and accept no arguments. Additionally, you can annotate the `fun` argument properly with `Callable[[], str]`:

```py
from typing import Callable


def decorator1(fun: Callable[[], str]):
    ...
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Callable method yet, but surely I will try it. Thank you